# What happened to my textures after importing from Substance Painter?

Tags: texturing, uv

This is the first time this issue has happened. So, here is what have in Substance:
[image]

And this is how it imports into blender:

[image]

[image]

why is it doing this and how do i fix it?

Comment: do you mean that it doesn't keep the unwrap that you've done in Substance?

Comment: i unwrapped it in blender the exact way it shows up in the UV editor

Comment: so maybe the UVs islands messed up in Substance?